# How can we calculate next base fee?

Tags: blockchain, gas, etherscan

I'm trying to understand gas in ethereum with EIP 1559.
During my search I found this article https://www.blocknative.com/blog/eip-1559-fees
(I have a light node deployed so I have access to block informations instantly).

In this article they say :
[image]

I tried with an increase of 12.5% ( when the gas limit is reached ), and I found the next block base fee. However when gas limit is not reached I do this :

percent = (<gas_used> / <gas_limit>) * 100 , and I now know that the block is percent% full

If block is filled to 100%, we increase by 12.5% the base fee. I deduced that if it's filled to 75% for example,  we increase by ( 0.75 * 12.5 ) = 9.375% the base fee at the next block. I have checked on etherscan and never found the good result ...

I have another question, when I visit blocknative calculator (https://www.blocknative.com/gas-estimator)
[image]

They do the opposite of what they say in their article. On the screen we can see that the base fee is 10.61, and max fee are 17/18gwei

but according to them :
[image]

Max fee = 10.61*2 + 2 = 23.22gwei

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 2):

Based on the CalcBaseFee function in the [source code of Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/509a64ffb9405942396276ae111d06f9bded9221/consensus/misc/eip1559/eip1559.go#L55), the process for determining the next base fee is as follows:

```
def predict_next_basefee(basefee, gasused, gaslimit):
    param = 4 # 4 for Ethereum, 8 for Polygon, ...

    tmp = (gasused - (gaslimit / 2)) * basefee / gaslimit / param
    if tmp == 0:
        return basefee
    elif tmp > 0:
        return basefee + max(1, tmp)
    else:
        return max(0, basefee + tmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain English, it means if gasUsedRatio (gasUsed/gasLimit) is 70%, then baseFee will increase by abs(70%-50%)/4 = 5%. If gasUsedRatio is 42%, then baseFee will decrease by abs(42%-50%)/4 = 2%.